# Unable to read application.properties in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am unable to read application.properties value in my project in classes that are injected as a bean from another project. My project is using another project which has classes which needs to read configuration from application.properties.
Mine is a maven project and a spring boot application having application.properties in src/main/resources folder and those properties values are defined in it.
What is it that I am missing that it is unable to read file values? Or is there is any other mechanism for setting these properties for classes loaded via component-scan

Below line of code works fine, it is able to read value from the application.properties:
        @PostConstruct
        void init() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
             System.out.println(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("env.host", 
        "default value"));
        }

Now there is another project which I am using in mine. When loading the classes those beans are getting initialized as dependency of another class, there also it tries to read same value in constants file as

```
   static final String HOST_PROPERTY = "${env.host}";
```

There this value is not getting initialized to value from applictaion.properties

Comment: Maybe you can add some piece of code you're using?

Comment: I have updated my question, let me know if more information is required

Comment: Please try, `@Value("${env.host}") private String HOST_PROPERTY;` May be `static` is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get application.properties values,you have to two option.
1) you can autowire Environment class and use its getProperty() method as

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
env.getProperty("${env.host}");
```

2)@Value annotation

```
@Value("${env.host}")
    String HOST_PROPERTY;
```